# What's the meaning of AWS Athena `key` icon next to the table name

Tags: amazon-athena

I've noticed a small key icon in AWS Athena UI:

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: Encrypted data table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Athena console list of tables, encrypted tables display a key-shaped icon.
[image]

Ref: [Amazon Athena - Creating tables based on encrypted datasets in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables-based-on-encrypted-datasets-in-s3.html)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: @vladsiv, added aws docs reference in the answer :)